# Stop setinterval after receiving value from server side

Tags: angular, setinterval, ionic4, reload

I am working on ionic 4 and angular. My app is content on flights schedule. What l am trying to do is to receive local notification from my server if specific flight is arrive. l use `setInterval` for reloading server to check if flights is arrive or not. The problem is when the flights are arrived the `setInterval` still reloading, also I used `clearInterval` but doesn't stop.

```
 async ActiveNotif() {

   this.ng.run(() => {
      // reloading 
      this.interval= setInterval(()=>{

        this.http.get('flight=' + this.id + '', {}, {})
        .then(data => {

          let FlightDetails = JSON.parse(data.data);
          this.identification = FlightDetails.identification.callsign;
          this.Fstatus = FlightDetails.status.generic.status.text;
          console.log(this.Fstatus)

        });

        //checking

        if (this.Fstatus == "landed") {

          this.localNotifications.schedule(
            [
              {
                id:0,
                title: 'Your flight has arrived',
                text: 'Your flight ' + this.identification + 'is arrived',
                trigger: { count: 1 },
                sound: "file://assets/one.mp3"
              },


            ]);
        }

      },10000)

      if (this.Fstatus == "landed") {


        clearInterval(this.interval)

      }

    })


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clearInterval` clause should be inside your `interval` so that the `if` is called periodically with the `get` result :)

Comment: Thank you for answering . i did that before , but he still running !

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution . Try to make `set interval` and `clear interval` as i do . 
Check out the solution .

```
async ActiveNotif() {

   this.ng.run(() => {
      // reloading 
      var time = setInterval(callingFunction , 10000);
      function callingFunction(){
        this.http.get('flight=' + this.id + '', {}, {})
        .then(data => {

            let FlightDetails = JSON.parse(data.data);
            this.identification = FlightDetails.identification.callsign;
            this.Fstatus = FlightDetails.status.generic.status.text;
            console.log(this.Fstatus)

        });



        if (this.Fstatus == "landed") {

            this.localNotifications.schedule(
                [
                {
                    id:0,
                    title: 'Your flight has arrived',
                    text: 'Your flight ' + this.identification + 'is arrived',
                    trigger: { count: 1 },
                    sound: "file://assets/one.mp3"
                },


                ]);
        }           
      if (this.Fstatus == "landed") {


        clearInterval(time)

      }
      }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http.get is an observable, not a promise. You need subscribe, not use "then". If you use httpClient, it's not necesary "parser", the data becomes as json yet

BTW I like much more the 'rxjs' timer, and use takeWhile to stopped, and switchMap to get the response

```
this.dataReaded=false;
timer(0,1000).pipe(
   takewhile(()=>!this.dataReaded),
   switchMap(()=>{
      return this.httpClient.get('flight=' + this.id + '', {}, {})
   }))
   .subscribe(res=>{
       const FlightDetails = data.data;
       this.identification = FlightDetails.identification.callsign;
       this.Fstatus = FlightDetails.status.generic.status.text;
       this.dataReaded=true;
   })
```

Comment: Thank you for answering .  unfortunately l am using cordova plugin http . [https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http] and she doesn't have subscribe .

Comment: Sorry, I see "http" and I supouse that was the httpClient of Angular. as curiosity, why use http plugin? If you use remember use ngZone to tell Angular some has changed.

Comment: i use http plugin to avoid cross domain . But do you have another solution ?

Comment: well, you can use 'rxjs' operator 'from' that convert a promise to Observable in switchMap `return from(this.http(....))` but I 'm not sure about this